# std::ifstream::imbue takes no effect

Tags: c++, utf-8, iostream, utf-16, wchar-t

I'm trying to read a text file written in utf-16 as utf-8.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    const wchar_t utf16_raw_string[] =  L"Привет!";
    const char    expected_string [] = u8"Привет!";
    std::ofstream("file.txt").write((char*)utf16_raw_string, sizeof(utf16_raw_string));

    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");
    ifs.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>() ));
    std::string got_string;
    ifs >> got_string;

    assert(got_string == expected_string);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that `imbue` takes no effect. No matter what `codecvt` is, `got_string` is always `"\x1f\x4@\x48\x42\x45\x4B\x4"` and I get the assertion. Any ideas?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with update 3.

Comment: A bit hazy on the details, but it might be necessary to imbue the locale ***before*** opening the file.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik of course, I did it. It doesn't help.